# How to develop JMeter Backend Listener?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to develop my own `JMeter Backend Listener`.

My goal:

- Receive each sample (SampleEvent - analyze each one. Example: write data to file)
- Get notified when test has started / ended

It will work in non-GUI mode.

After it is developed, how is it supposed to be added into JMeter (should it be added as an external .JAR, similar to plugins in /lib/ext)?

If I understood correct, I should -

Extend:

```
public class MY_CLASS_NAME extends AbstractBackendListenerClient implements Runnable {
```

In JMX:

```
<BackendListener guiclass="BackendListenerGui" 
                 testclass="BackendListener" 
                 testname="Backend Listener" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="classname">MY_CLASS_NAME</stringProp>
</BackendListener>
```

Is there any API that I can use to add my `Backend Listener` to `JMX` file without opening UI (JMX test runs from Java code)?

Any inputs / example would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to develop a subclass of [AbstractBackendListenerClient](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html)

JMeter will expose it in UI so that you set in XML, don

See an example here:

- https://gist.github.com/rdpanek/c1065b889483a93cdb06

And a full tutorial here:

- http://theworkaholic.blogspot.fr/2015/05/graphs-for-jmeter-using-elasticsearch.html